# Resetting array back to array[0] in a while loop java

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop

I am trying to get my while loop always reset to array[0]. I am trying to make it so that I can say what my favorite class is, and if need be change my mind after I have chosen the first one. Currently the code only lets me output array[0] then [1] then [2] or [2] > [3] or [1] > [3] but not [2] > [1] or [3] > [1]. Thanks. I am using Java. edit** If it wasn't clear I am talking about the second while loop.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Hobby1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int numClass;
        int a;
        int b;
        String j;
        System.out.println("How many classes");
        numClass = scan.nextInt();
        j = scan.nextLine();
        String[] Class = new String[numClass];
        a = 0;
        while (a < numClass) {
            System.out.println("What is class " + a + "?");
            Class[a] = scan.nextLine();
            a++;
        }
        System.out.println("Which class is most important");
        String input = scan.nextLine();
        b = 0;
        boolean be = true;

        while (be == true) {


            if (input.contains(Class[b])) {
                System.out.println("The class " + Class[b] + " is most important");
                input = scan.nextLine();
             }

            b++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have few problems here:

- ***while (be == true)*** - you can just use  ***while (be)*** // ***be*** is boolean
- you never put  ***be = false;***, so you will have an infinite loop
- how you iterate the array ***Class*** to compare to each value of it? you just check once in increment order ***b***, you need to loop all array not only the current element on ***b***

Ex:

```
for(String currentClass: Class){
   if (currentClass.equals(input)) {
       System.out.println("The class " + currentClass + " is most important");
   }
}
```

Check this and try to fix your code.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I understand that I had an infinite loop, it was a testing group for the unlimited amounts of input.